# Можно ли использовать Django rest framework для передачи контекста в html шаблон?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Помогите разобраться, можно/правильно ли делать разработку бэкэнда на DRF если на фронте не будет JS-фрейморков, а только html и немого Jquery? Т.е. я имею ввиду заменить стандартный MVT (views, forms и т.д) способ на DRF и принимать на фронте JSON. Если можно, то с примером передачи в шаблон контекста.

Comment: Если у вас не будет js-фреймворков, то и фронта не будет, принимать JSON будет нечем.

Comment: Коротко и ясно, спасибо!